# White Bar Under Tor Status Onion Icon?

Tags: onion-routing

I am using Tor in Tails 1.8.1.  I am attempting to upgrade online to 1.8.2 yet I'm noticing that the Tor onion status logo is green yet it has a white bar at the bottom of it.  I've seen this before and I ignored it.  I am not using Window camo, rather the default GUI. Strangely enough there doesn't seem to be any answers to this online.  Thanks.